# Error in return statement

Tags: python

I am facing issue with return statement in function real string. The function is running properly when I run separately,but when I run within the program, it is not returning the result. The function real string should return result as following: `((.((....)).).)`

```
import numpy
import array
class Structure :
    def __init__(self): 
        self.paired =[]
        self.unpaired =[]
    def merge(self, s):
        for i in s.paired :
            self.paired.append(i)
        for i in s.unpaired :
            self.unpaired.append(i)
    def __str__(self):
        return "paired\n"+str(self.paired) +"\n unpaired \n"+str(self.unpaired)+"\n"
def l(ch) :

    if (ch=='A') :
        return 0
    elif (ch=='C'):
        return 1
    elif (ch=='U') :
        return 2
    elif (ch =='G') :
        return 3
    else :
        print "error"

def cost(i,j,M,w,seq,compare): #Defining the cost functions or can say recurrence formula
    j_unpaired = M[i,j-1]
    i_unpaired = M[i+1,j]
    paired = M[i+1,j-1] + w[l(seq[i]), l(seq[j])]

    return compare(j_unpaired,i_unpaired,paired)  #return comparison of the three relations

def fill(M, w, seq, compare): #function defining how to fill up the values 
    n = len(seq)
    for k in range(5,n):
        for i in range(0,n-k):
            j = k+i
            c = cost(i,j,M,w,seq,compare)
            M[i,j] = c

def trace(M, w, seq, compare, horizontal_arrow, vertical_arrow) :
    i = horizontal_arrow
    j = vertical_arrow
    struct = Structure()
    while (j != i-1):
        if M[i,j] == M[i,j-1] :
            struct.unpaired.append(j)
            j -= 1

        elif M[i,j] == M[i+1,j] :

            struct.unpaired.append(i)

            i += 1
        elif M[i,j] == M[i+1,j-1] + w[l(seq[i]), l(seq[j])] :

            struct.paired.append((i,j))
            i += 1
            j -= 1
        else:
            print "error"

    return struct

def real_string(M, w, seq, compare, horizontal_arrow, vertical_arrow) : 
    trace=dict()
    struct = Structure()
    for element in struct.unpaired:
        trace[element] = '.'

    for element in struct.paired:
        trace[element[0]] = '('
        trace[element[1]] = ')'

    return list(trace.values())##The glitch is here;not showing result.

f =open("example.fasta","r")
def readSeq(FASTA):
    for line in FASTA:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        return line


seq=readSeq(f)

n = len(seq)

w = numpy.zeros([4,4],int)
w.fill(0)
w[l('A'), l('U')] = 1
w[l('U'), l('A')] = 1 
w[l('G'), l('C')] = 1
w[l('C'), l('G')] = 1
M = numpy.zeros([n,n],int) #initialisation of matrix
fill(M, w, seq, max) #Filling matrix M with scores
print M
# perform traceback 
s = trace(M, w, seq, max, 0, n-1)
print str(s)
print seq
result=real_string(M, w, seq, max,0,n-1)
print "".join(result)
```

When I am running the code as following it works :

```
yourDict=dict()

unpaired = [13, 11, 2, 8, 7, 6, 5]

paired = [(0, 14), (1, 12), (3, 10), (4, 9)]



for element in unpaired:
    yourDict[element] = '.'

for element in paired:
    yourDict[element[0]] = '('
    yourDict[element[1]] = ')'

print "".join(list(yourDict.values()))
```

Comment: And what does it return instead? What does `print "".join(result)` print at the end?

Comment: doesn't return anything.Just terminates the program

Comment: So you mean `result` is empty? And how do you run it separately when it works?

Comment: yes...when I am running the function separately,it is showing result.But,here in this code,it is empty

Comment: How exactly do you run it when it works?

Comment: @SayaneShome as you have print statements at the end, it either prints something (at least empty lines) or throws an error.

Comment: @Szymon I included the code in my query.

Comment: @hege_hegedus yes..I am wondering why it isn't returning the desired lines..Am I calling the struct.unpaired and struct.paired wrongly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `real_string` to this, as it has wrong arguments:

```
def real_string(struct) : 
    trace=dict()
    for element in struct.unpaired:
        trace[element] = '.'

    for element in struct.paired:
        trace[element[0]] = '('
        trace[element[1]] = ')'

    return list(trace.values())
```

and call it like this:

```
# perform traceback 
s = trace(M, w, seq, max, 0, n-1)
print str(s)
print seq
result=real_string(s)
print "".join(result)
```

Comment: It is prompting now "result=real_string(struct)
NameError: name 'struct' is not defined"

Comment: You copied the code wrong. It should be `result = real_string(s)`. These kind of copy errors can be prevented by using copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Your `real_string` function initializes a new `Structure`:

`struct = Structure()`

`__init__` of `Structure` creates empty lists for paired and unpaired. You then iterate through those empty lists in `real_string` which doesn't put anything into `trace` dictionary.

So the function then returns an empty list.

I don't know what exactly you tried to achieve but it seems like you're not using most of the parameters passed to your function. Quite likely you wanted to use `s` returned from `trace`:

```
s = trace(M, w, seq, max, 0, n-1)
```

So make it the parameter of `real_string` and remove the initialization of struct.